# set radiobutton in loadComplete of grid

Tags: jqgrid

```
        $("#addressList").jqGrid({
        url: '/Storage/Shipping/GetCustomerAddresses?q=2&Customerid=' + $("#saveCustomerID").val(),
        datatype: "Json",
        jsonReader: {
            root: "Data.rows",
            page: "Data.page",
            total: "Data.total",
            records: "Data.records",
            repeatitems: true,
            userdata: "userdata",
            cell: "cell"
        },
        colNames: ['', 'Line 1', 'Line 2', 'City', 'State'],
        colModel: [
                         { name: 'myradio', width: 30, fixed: true, align: 'center', resizable: false, sortable: false,
                             formatter: function (cellValue, option) {
                                 return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '" />';
                             } 
                         },
                         { name: 'Line1', index: 'Line1', width: 250 },
                         { name: 'Line2', index: 'Line2', width: 250 },
                         { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 210 },
                         { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 75 }
                    ],
        page: 1,
        rowNum: 50,
        rowList: [20, 50, 100],
        pager: '#pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        grouping: false,
        caption: "Addresses",
        mtype: "POST",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        loadonce: true,
        sortable: false,
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            var radio = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]');
            radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
            $("#saveCustomerAddressID").val(rowid.toString());
            return true; // allow row selection
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var grid_ids = $("#addressList").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < grid_ids.length; i++) {
                if ($("#saveCustomerAddressID").val() == grid_ids[i]) {
                    {
                        $("#addressList").jqGrid('setSelection', grid_ids[i], true);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //, postdata: { CustomerID: $("#saveCustomerID").val() }
    });
```

The above code sets the selection correctly in loadcomplete.  The $("#saveCustomerAddressID").val() is the rowid fro the JSON Data. 
The radiobutton is set in the  beforeSelectRow. I know the row number and grid column of of the radiobutton to be set, but how do you set the radiobutton?

Comment: if the code is working well for u in beforeSelectRow and same you want to use in loadComplete, then add the same code to loadComplete what is the problem with that? ofcourse yo can not use this 'e' then, but you said you have row number and grid column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have row number and grid column, then it shouldn't be difficult. get the id(css) of that column where you have your radio button(check developer tools for this). now lets say that radio button is in a column name "Demo"

so the id would look like something like this i suppose

```
var demo= $("'#'+rowid+'Demo'")//check developer tools for confirmation

demo.attr('checked', 'checked');
$("#saveCustomerAddressID").val(rowid.toString());//continue with you loadComplete code
```

and for set selection  use setSelection method of jqgrid after this continue with your code of loadcomplete

Comment: .attr.attr should be .attr above.

Comment: yes it working,thanks.  added var radio = $("#"+ $("#saveCustomerAddressID").val()).find('input[type="radio"]'); in loadcomplete to select the cell with radio button.  $("#saveCustomerAddressID").val() is the rowid.

Comment: are you going to mark it as answer, it may help some one else.